# Assign an arraylist to an array in java

Tags: java

Is there anyway I could assign an arrayList to an array in Java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use `toArray()` in List.

See:

```
  List a = new ArrayList();
  a.add("foo");
  a.add("bar");
  System.out.println(a); // prints [foo, bar]

  Object[] myArray = a.toArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(myArray[i]); // prints 'foo' and 'bar'
  }
```

See online, in [ideone](http://ideone.com/pjdcs).

Answer (score 2):

Object[] array = myArrayList.toArray(new Object[myArrayList.size()]);?

Comment: They are different types, so you cannot simply do  Object[] ar = myArrayList;

Comment: Maybe you're trying to say Object[] array = myArrayList.toArray(new Object[myArrayList.size()]);?

Answer (score 0):

Call [List.toArray()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray())